# usb Joystick Detected, but registers no input

Tags: usb-device, joystick

I have two `Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.7` systems, each running kernel `2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64`

The same overall packages/configuration are applied to both, and I have installed `kmod-joydev` from the `elrepo` repository. On one of the systems(`dell t3600 workstation`) joysticks detect and work perfectly.

On the other, a `Dell m6400 notebook`, the same usb devices are detected, but not functional, even at a raw level if I issue a `cat /dev/input/js0`

It does not output any noise as the device is moved/Buttons pressed

`lsusb:`

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 068e:00f3 CH Products, Inc. Fighterstick
```

`lsmod | grep joydev:`

```
joydev                 10670  0
```

Other than hardware configuration I have tried to get these two systems to be exactly identical. Unfortunately I'm not much good with peripheral troubleshooting, so I'm not entirely sure what else to check.

I have tried multiple usb ports on the system that is not functional, and have tried other, non-joystick devices on the system and those function properly.

Any thing that might give me a new avenue to explore would be fantastic.